# Eager Loading in Laravel Polymorphic Relationship is working but N+1 query prob still exist

Tags: laravel, eloquent, polymorphism, laravel-5, eager-loading

**Without Access a related model**

Everything seem nice and work well with eager loading. When without access a model related to the polymorphic model.
[Everything works well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41K2I.png)

**But when i try to access other model**

$club->events()->get()->count()

```
<tbody>
                            @foreach($Clubs as $club)
                                <tr>
                                    <td><a href="{{url('database/club/').'/'.$club->id}}">{{$club->club_name}}</a>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>{{$club->origin}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$club->hp}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$club->email}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$club->location}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$club->category}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$club->rating}}</td>
                        //This cause N+1 problem to happen
                                    <td>{{$club->events()->get()->count()}}</td>

                       //I will get more problem when access more!!!!!
                                    {{--<td>{{$club->records()->get()->count()}}</td>--}}

                                </tr>
                            @endforeach
</tbody>
```

[This is my database structure. The Records table will record all the participant from Event/Branch Event/Club](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PiqRp.png)

**My clubController**

```
 public function index()
{
    $Clubs = $this->club->with(['records','records.recordable', 'events'])->get();

    return view('pages.database.club', compact(['Clubs']));
}
```

**Record Model**

```
    class Record extends Model
{

    public function recordable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

    public function events()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany('App\Event', 'recordable', 'records', 'recordable_id');
    }

    public function sub_events()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany('App\Sub_Event', 'recordable', 'records', 'recordable_id');
    }

    public function clubs()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany('App\Club', 'recordable', 'records', 'recordable_id');
    }


    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
    }
```

**Club Model**

```
class Club extends Model
{
    public function records()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Record','recordable');
    }

    // public function users()
    // {
    //     return $this->belongsToMany('App\User','club_user');
    // }
    public function events()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Event');
    }
```

**Event Model**

```
class Event extends Model
{  
    public function sub_events()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Sub_Event', 'event_id');
    }

    public function records()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Record', 'recordable');
    }

    // public function users()
    // {
    //     return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'event_user');
    // }

    public function club()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Club');
    }
```

**Reference**

I try to search thru the answer but its always seem outdated. I tried the solution from 
http stackoverflow.com/questions/26727088/laravel-eager-loading-polymorphic-relations-related-models 
but still unable to solve this problem.

**Extra**
I didn't have enough reputation to post more than 2 photos to describe my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You accessing Your loaded relationship wrong. When executing `$club->events()->get()->count()` You asking `$club` model to get relationship **again** from database instead of trying to get relationship which is already loaded in eager loading.

The right way would be to change those two lines to: `$club->events->count()`.

Comment: You are very professional !!! Your answer works great!!!! 
Thanks for your help. How you learn these??

Comment: Practice makes perfect :) The more problems You facing, the more knowledge You gaining over time.